# Connecting guitar to Amplitube

Tags: guitar, pc

I have a problem with my ASUS r553l. There's only one jack input for mic/headphones. I tried to plug my guitar via a jack adapter to it but it seems to not be recognized by the computer. I have Realtek HD Audio manager installed but Amplitube can't find my audio device. What should I do ?

Comment: You can get an adaptor to split out the combined jack to separate mic and headphones. Alternatively, get a USB adaptor with a guitar-specific input.

Comment: Seconding a usb audio interface. You don't need anything special unless you want to spend the money. You can find a cheap interface for under $50 USD. stay away from M Audio gear. There is ALWAYS a better alternative for the same price. http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Audio-Interfaces/UCG102/p/P0198

Comment: For another datum point - I really really like the M-Audio sound interfaces I have used. Very low latency, superb quality - better than a lot of the competition at that price. So shop around.

Answer (score -2):

Amp modeling software really don't work on laptops. I've had numerous experiences with laptops mixing the jack input with the microphone input causing unwanted distortion and really high latency. The only way I got it to work properly was by using a jack to USB cable as suggested by the comment. You should consider the rocksmith cable. I use it on guitar rig 5 regularly and gives a much better sound quality than a normal jack with an adapter. Or alternatively buy a USB soundcard that has a jack. Check out the m-audio fastrack sound card or anything that's similar

Comment: A RockSmith is not a "jack to USB cable". It is an active electronic device called a **digital audio interface**, or more properly and **analog-to-digital converter**. Good digital audio interfaces cost a good deal of money. There is no "cable" solution for connecting a guitar to a cheap laptop computer.